# Apply a Yaw to Pitch and Roll

Tags: trigonometry

I have a unit vector of two angles. A roll, rotation around Y-axis; and a pitch, rotation around X-axis. If I apply a yaw, rotation around the Z-axis, how do I calculate what the new angles are of the vector in roll and pitch?

Comment: I'd suggest converting your vector into $(x, y, z)$ coordinates, applying the rotation, and converting it back.

Comment: What is a vector of two angles?  Usually roll is around x and pitch is around y.